# Comment dire 'lid' ? (laptop)

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, informatique

L'autre jour j'ai voulu expliquer à mes élèves :

> *How to Run Your Laptop With the Lid Closed.*

Voir [pcmag](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-run-your-laptop-with-the-lid-closed) ou [dummies.com](https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-change-what-closing-the-laptop-lid-does/)

[image]

Je leur ai dit :

> Comment faire fonctionner votre ordinateur portable avec le couvercle fermé

Je n'ai pas été compris.  Ils étaient surpris de l'emploi du mot couvercle. Après mes explications, ils m'ont dit que le mot couvercle ne s'utilise pas dans ce contexte et en français on dit plutôt écran (de l'ordinateur portable).

- Ont-ils raison ?
- N'existe-t-il pas un mot pour désigner le *laptop's lid* ?

Comment: Dimitris, in English, that is not a lid. I'm finding that sometimes your questions in English use non-standard terms. That part of a laptop is called a "panel" or "screen".  lids in English are for cans or containers. Also, called a cover.

Comment: @Lambie : See the article from pcmag. It is used as technical term. I cannot understand what's the issue here. See also here: https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-change-what-closing-the-laptop-lid-does/

Comment: @Lambie That's not Dimitris saying "lid" it's what is used on the site of PC magazine  (a site dedicated to  computers & computing). And [plenty of other specialist sites](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=the+lid+of+your+PC&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&tbs=) use it so as well. Just not me or Dimitris.  The screen is not the lid, maybe we could say the screen is part of the lid.

Comment: @Lambie Lid can be used in this context : https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-change-what-closing-the-laptop-lid-does/

Comment: Ok, fine. I prefer screen or panel.

Comment: @Dimitris I suppose the reaction of Lambie is your answer. Couvercle makes us think about something detachable, which is how it's generally used. It seems to be kind of a misnomer, even if it's used in the tech world, which is why people unfamiliar with the term could be confused at first.

Comment: @Simon Lambie was reacting to "lid", not to *couvercle*. And I wouldn't say "lid" is a misnomer since so many people use it.

Comment: @None The reaction of Lambie towards "lid" is the same as his students towards "couvercle". The feeling towards the term is the same in English or in French. Misnomer: "a wrong or *inaccurate* name or designation." A misnomer can be accepted and widely used. This is also why I used "kind of" to put emphasis on that nuance.

Comment: @Dimitris   I wish my Greek was as good as your English. Et j'ai remarqué que tu avais fait d'énormes progrès en français.

Comment: @Simon Thank you for explaining that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certaines personnes disent, et on trouve en cherchant sur Google, « [couvercle de l'ordinateur](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22couvercle%20de%20l%27ordinateur%22&lr=&safe=images&as_qdr=all&ei=Oh58YbymDqWalwS9wJnACw&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi8q_ChgvDzAhUlzYUKHT1gBrgQ8tMDegQIARBB&biw=1860&bih=909&dpr=1) ». J'ai fait la même recherche avec « [capot](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=capot%20de%20l%27ordinateur&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&tbs=) » et je suis surprise de voir que c'est moins employé que « couvercle ». On trouve aussi « [replier l'écran](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=replier%20l%27%C3%A9cran%20&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&tbs=) », mais c'est anecdotique par rapport aux deux autres, même si on y ajoute « [écran replié](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22%C3%A9cran%20repli%C3%A9%22&lr=&safe=images&as_qdr=all&ei=aTZ8YdanNqaUlwT6iK34Dg&oq=%22%C3%A9cran%20repli%C3%A9%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BggAEAcQHjoICAAQgAQQsQM6BwgAELEDEEM6BAgAEEM6BQgAEIAEOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToICAAQBxAKEB46CAgAEAgQBxAeOggIABAHEAUQHjoKCAAQCBAHEAoQHjoKCAAQBxAFEAoQHkoECEEYAVDcNlicTmDiW2gBcAB4AIABYYgBwAeSAQIxM5gBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiWgKWqmfDzAhUmyoUKHXpEC-8Q4dUDCA0&uact=5) » on est loin du compte. Quant à dire « fermer l'écran » ou « écran fermé », sans geste ou dessin à l'appui, je ne le dirais pas car ça peut être ambigu, certains disant « fermé » pour « éteint ».

Comment: Que veux-tu dire par anecdotique? L'écran replié est très précis.

Comment: @Simon [Anecdotique](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/anecdotique) :  ne présente pas d'intérêt général. Syn : contingent, accessoire, insignifiant, marginal. Il suffit de comparer les chiffres, ce n'est pas le même ordre de grandeur.

Comment: Ah d'accord, je croyais que tu faisais référence à l'expression elle-même, mais tu parles du nombre d'utilisation. En effet, on dirait que c'est moins utilisé, c'est dommage parce que c'est un terme beaucoup plus "approprié" pour décrire la situation.

Comment: « Comment faire fonctionner votre ordinateur portable avec *l'écran **re**fermé* ? »
Utiliser *écran*, centre de la question semble la solution la plus intuitive, d'autant plus que le *clavier* est en soit le second élément important, et l'on n'en parle pas en désignant le dessous comme d'un *plat/pot… sous le couvercle* ni comme *capot sous le clavier*. au pire, un ergoteur pourrait dire « avec le dessus [qui contient l'écran et sa protection extérieure] refermé »